# Similar method like TRY_CAST in presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino, presto-jdbc

In SQL server, there is TRY_CAST method available to check if cast is possible or not. If cast is not possible then it will set NULL as value.

Is there any similar method available in presto? Or How to achieve similar behavior in presto?

Comment: What are you trying to cast here, and can you include sample data?

Comment: I want to parse date from varchar. Sample data: "4/11/2019 12:29:49 PM" 
If date is not correct then it should set NULL.

Comment: Not sure if Presto has a try cast, but if it doesn't, then you're basically out of luck.  Instead, you'll have to know beforehand what the format of your date strings are.

Answer (score 2):

That function has existed for many years. You can find it in the [docs](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html?highlight=try_cast#try_cast).

```sql
SELECT try_cast('abc' AS bigint)
```

=>

```
 _col0
-------
  NULL
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use TRY_CAST to convert a string into a timestamp and compare it with my own converting code.

```
select 
CASE
 WHEN LENGTH(received)<3 
   THEN NULL
 ELSE DATE(DATE_PARSE(substr(received, 1,10), '%m/%d/%Y'))  
 END AS "RECEIVED_CV"
,DATE(TRY_CAST(received AS TIMESTAMP)) AS RECEIVED
from (table)
```

The result is very interesting. My code will produce the date but the TRY_CAST will produce null. The original string value is like this "02/05/2021 15:45:57.000000"

[Comparison of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoyXM.png)